# Google cloude authentification without json

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

So im using a small programm to get license plates from images. I do that by sending google vision the image and searching the text that i get bex for licens plates that are like a regular expression.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat May 23 19:42:18 2020

@author: Odatas
"""


import io
import os
from google.cloud import vision_v1p3beta1 as vision
import cv2
import re

# Setup google authen client key
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'client_key.json'

# Source path content all images
SOURCE_PATH = "F:/Radsteuereintreiber/Bilder Temp/"


def recognize_license_plate(img_path):

    # Read image with opencv
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)

    # Get image size
    height, width = img.shape[:2]

    # Scale image
    img = cv2.resize(img, (800, int((height * 800) / width)))

    # Save the image to temp file
    cv2.imwrite(SOURCE_PATH + "output.jpg", img)

    # Create new img path for google vision
    img_path = SOURCE_PATH + "output.jpg"

    # Create google vision client
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    # Read image file
    with io.open(img_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
    # Recognize text
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    return texts


path = SOURCE_PATH + 'IMG_20200513_173356.jpg'
plate = recognize_license_plate(path)
for text in plate:
    # read description
    license_plate = text.description
    # change all symbols to whitespace.
    license_plate = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\n\.]', ' ', license_plate)
    # see if some text matches pattern
    test = re.findall('[A-Z]{1,3}\s[A-Z]{1,2}\s\d{1,4}', str(license_plate))
    # stop if you found someting
    if test is not None:
        break
try:
    print(test[0])
except Exception:
    print("No plate found")
```

As you can see i set my envoiremental variable to the client_key.json at the start. When i distribut my programm i dont like to send out my key to every user. So i would like to include the key inside the program directly.

I tried it by using the explicit credential method by google with a json created inside the program like this:

```
def explicit():



    #creat json
    credentials={ REMOVED: INSIDE HER WOULD BE ALL THE INFORMATION FROM THE JSON KEY FILE. 
}

    json_credentials=json.dumps(credentials)

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        json_credentials)

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
# [END auth_cloud_explicit]
```

But i get the error.

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: content of my json again removed

So i not sure if i have to switch to an api based call and how do i call the same functionality then? Because i have to upload a picture obvriously i dont even think thats possible through an api call.

So im kinda lost. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have a solution but I don't understand what do you want to do? Instead of sending a service account key file, you will hardcode the value in a python file, a plain text file. Why are you doing this? For user convenience or for security?

Comment: The user gets the programm as an executable. So he doesnt have acces to the code. So when i write it into the script it is more secure as when i would just give him the key.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be able to make API calls against *your* Google Cloud project, then including your service account key, either as a JSON file or inline in your code, is basically equivalent, and either way the user would have access to your key.

This is generally not advised though: even a minimally scoped service account would be able to make requests and potentially incur charges against your account.

An alternative would be to deploy your own API inside your Google Cloud project which wraps the call to the Vision API. This would allow you to protect your service account key, and also to rate limit or even block calls to this API if you need to.

Your script or library would then make calls to this custom API instead of directly to the Vision API.

Comment: That is a really nice solution i didnt even knew that this was possible. But wouldnt calls to this api cost me resources. Like im calling vision which counts as 1 access and now i count an api for 1 access and vision which would be two access?

Also since in never developed my own API how would that look like? Can i do it in python? Do you have some resources?